# Flex 4 - Is it possible to animate UITextField

Tags: actionscript, flex4

Is it possible to give move effect on a UITextField.

```
var aminolabel:UITextField;
var aminoLabelMove:Move = new Move(aminolabel);                     
aminoLabelMove.xFrom = 0;
aminoLabelMove.xTo = 100
aminoLabelMove.duration = 1300;                 
aminoLabelMove.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextField could not have animations like move. Which internally calls transformX, transformY. Can have Face effect animation.

**Solution** 
Add UITextField instance to a UIComponent and apply the move effect to the UIComponent.

Example

```
var aminolabel:UITextField;
var aminoLabelUI:UIComponent;

aminoLabelUI.addChild(aminolabel);

var aminoLabelMove:Move = new Move(aminoLabelUI);                     
aminoLabelMove.xFrom = 0;
aminoLabelMove.xTo = 100
aminoLabelMove.duration = 1300;                 
aminoLabelMove.play();
```